# How to use `replace` of directive definition?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

In this document: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive , it says that there is a `replace` configuration for directives:

> **template** - replace the current element with the contents of the HTML. The replacement process migrates all of the attributes / classes from the old element to the new one. See the Creating Components section below for more information.

**javascript code**

```
app.directive('myd1', function(){
  return {
    template: '<span>directive template1</span>',
    replace: true
  }
});

app.directive('myd2', function(){
  return {
    template: '<span>directive template2</span>',
    replace: false
  }
});
```

**html code**

```
<div myd1>
  original content should be replaced
</div>
<div myd2>
  original content should NOT be replaced
</div>
```

But the final page is looking like:

```
directive template1
directive template2
```

It seems the `replace` doesn't work. Do I miss anything?

Live demo: http://plnkr.co/edit/rGIgmjO81X2UxJohL4HM?p=preview

Answer (score 180, accepted):

You are getting confused with `transclude: true`, which would append the inner content.

`replace: true` means that the content of the directive template will replace the element that the directive is declared on, in this case the `<div myd1>` tag.

http://plnkr.co/edit/k9qSx15fhSZRMwgAIMP4?p=preview

For example **without** `replace:true`

```
<div myd1><span class="replaced" myd1="">directive template1</span></div>
```

and **with** `replace:true`

```
<span class="replaced" myd1="">directive template1</span>
```

As you can see in the latter example, the div tag is indeed *replaced*.

Comment: What about transclude: 'element'. It seems to do the same thing as replace: 'true' when using ng-transclude.

Comment: Is replace: false, the same as not using replace at all?

Comment: @Neil Yes. Leaving it off is the same as `false`

Comment: @CMCDragonkai 'replace' should have a template defined, 'transclude' need not?

Comment: A good example of when you would use `replace` and `transclude` together is if you wanted to add an `ng-click` or some other directive within the directive vs markup

Comment: `replace` is now deprecated

Comment: @Robert does 'replace' would have a replacement or is it gone for good?

Comment: @cirovladimir, see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24194972/why-is-replace-deprecated-in-angularjs

Answer (score 12):

As the documentation states, 'replace' determines whether the current element is replaced by the directive. The other option is whether it is just added to as a child basically. If you look at the source of your plnkr, notice that for the second directive where replace is false that the div tag is still there. For the first directive it is not.

First result:

```
<span myd1="">directive template1</span>
```

Second result:

```
<div myd2=""><span>directive template2</span></div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Replace [True | False (default)]

> Effect

```
1.  Replace the directive element.
```

> Dependency:

```
1. When replace: true, the template or templateUrl must be required.
```

Answer (score 0):

Also i got this error if i had the comment in tn top level of template among with the actual root element.

```
<!-- Just a commented out stuff -->
<div>test of {{value}}</div>
```