# How to style a directive from the outside?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive which I want to customize with style attribute from where I invoke it, as follows:

```
<plant-stages style="-webkit-transform: scale(.8); border: solid blue 1px"
    stages="stages"
    affectedstages="accident.stages"
    change-page="changePage(stage)"
    title="Les étapes du cycle suceptibles d'être affectées"
    subtitle="Taper sur une des étape de la plante pour obtenir des informations détaillées"
></plant-stages>
```

By passing in style attributes, I'd like they apply to the resulting HTML from the directive, as any standard HTML directive would do.

The partial code snippet is as follows:

```
<figure class="cornStages">
    <div></div>
</figure>
```

And the directive itself is as follows:

```
app.directive('plantStages', function ($compile) {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        templateUrl: 'corn.figure.plant.stages.html',
        transclude: true,
        scope: { 
            stages: "=",
            affectedstages:"=",
            changePage: "&",
            title: "@",
            subtitle : "@"
        },
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be to store the style in the scope by adding `style: '@'` in the definition of the scope of the directive and then to add  `ng-style="style"` in your template.

I've made a working example on [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/9H39j/19/).

The code is the following:

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <my-little-directive style="color: red"></my-little-directive>
    <my-little-directive style="color: blue"></my-little-directive>
    <my-little-directive style="-webkit-transform: scale(.8); border: solid blue 1px"></my-little-directive>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
angular.module('myApp',[]).directive('myLittleDirective', function() {
   return {
        restrict: 'E',
       template: '<div ng-style="style">{{style}}</div>',
        replace: true,
        scope: { 
            style : "@"
        },
};
});
```

Comment: Weird enough, that was my first idea which I tried without success. I give it a try again as I saw your fiddle working. Keep posted :-) What's the purpose of the replace: true btw?

Comment: If it's not working in your code, I'm afraid that you'll have to post a plunker/jsfiddle reproducing the issue. ^^"

Comment: It works nice, the only difference I had is I hadn't put the replace:true. Can you quickly tell me what it does?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285635/how-to-use-replace-of-directive-definition :)

Comment: Understood. Yet I wonder the very difference with transclude (concepts are not yet all very clear to me, need more experience :-) )

Comment: With `transclude`, the directive will delete the original content, but it will be available for reinsertion within the template through the use of the directive `ng-transclude`. I've never really use that except for looking what it was doing ^^"