# Angular JS : replace property in directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, directive

In angular JS, we have a property called replace with possible values as true or false while defining directive. But i dont understand how this property will be used. Will it replace the HTML parent element when it is set true

Comment: It will replace the DOM element where you put your directive by the template of your directive.

Comment: The best explaination I have seen is [SO: Angular directive replace=true](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22498024/5535245)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Angular directive replace=true](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)

Answer (score 0):

Actual template:

```
<div class="parent">
 <my-dir><div>Hello world!!</div></my-dir>
</div>
```

if **replace** is **true**, mir-dir tag will be removed.

```
 <div class="parent">
    <div>Hello world!!</div>
    </div>
```

if **replace** is **false**, mir-dir tag will not be removed.

```
 <div class="parent">
     <my-dir><div>Hello world!!</div></my-dir>
    </div>
```

Hope you understand!!. let me know if you have any queries.

Answer (score 0):

**Replace** - If set to true will replace the element having a directive on it with a template.

**PS** : You have to use templateUrl/template along with replace.

HTML

```
<div angular></div>
<div class="angular"></div>
<angular>Simple angular directive</angular>
```

JS

```
var App = angular.module('App', []);

App.directive('angular', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'ECMA',
    replace: true,
    template: '<img src="http://goo.gl/ceZGf"/>'
  };
});
```

Above example angular directive will replace its contents "**Simple angular directive**" by contents in template i.e "**Replaced content**".

Answer (score 0):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$compile) of angular (replace option):

> true - the template will replace the directive's element.
>
> false - the template will replace the contents of the directive's element.

Imagine you have a directive named `my-directive` with the template `<span>directive</span>` and your html code is `<div my-directive></div>`. Then `replace : false` results in:

```
<div my-directive><span class="replaced" my-directive="">directive</span></div>
```

And `replace : true` results in:

```
<span class="replaced" my-directive="">directive</span>
```

Please note that this option is deprecated.

See related questions:

[How to use `replace` of directive definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285635/how-to-use-replace-of-directive-definition)

[Explain replace=true in Angular Directives (Deprecated)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22497706/angular-directive-replace-true)