# AngularJS Directive as a comment

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm just playing with angular directives, but somehow the comment way to add directives is not showing up. Here is the markup.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <script src="angular.js"></script>
</head>

    <body ng-app="directive-app">

         <first-directive></first-directive>

         <div first-directive></div> 

         <div class=first-directive></div> 

         <!-- directive: first-directive -->     

         <script src="main.js"></script> 


</body>
</html>
```

Directive definition

```
var app=angular.module('directive-app',[]);

app.directive("firstDirective", function() {
    return {
        restrict : "EACM",  
        templateUrl : 'template.html'
    };
});
```

In template.html there is one h1 element. But comment way to add directives is not showing up in UI and in which case comment approach is even required.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Set `replace` option to `true` as follows

```
app.directive("firstDirective", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EACM",
    replace: true,
    templateUrl: 'template.html'
  };
});
```

Here's [demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/LqF4pONHwncuORgFfrlW?p=preview).

Comment: ya, that works can you give some explanation about that. Why replace is only required in case of comment

Comment: @MahtabAlam First, get yourself familiar with the `replace` option, see https://stackoverflow.com/a/15286383/87972. When `replace` is `false`, Angular will try to put the template content inside the comment, that's why it's not visible. When `replace` is `true`, Angular will replace the comment with the template content, that's why it's visible.

Comment: Thanks that helps @Hoa

Comment: Hey, I want to know that what are the cases where we need to use directive as a comment?