# AngularJS Material Dialog using component as template

Tags: css, angularjs, angularjs-material

I have an angular component which I want to use in an AngularJS Material dialog:

```
return $mdDialog.show({
    template: '<publish-dialog user="$ctrl.user" target-collection="$ctrl.targetCollection"></publish-dialog>',
    controller: function () {
        this.user = user;
        this.targetCollection = targetCollection;
    },
    controllerAs: '$ctrl',
    targetEvent: event,
    clickOutsideToClose: true
});
```

The problem is, that when defining the template like this, the generated html looks like this:

```
<md-dialog>
  <publish-dialog>
    <md-toolbar></md-toolbar>
    <md-dialog-content></md-dialog-content>
    <md-dialog-actions></md-dialog-actions>
  </publish-dialog>
<md-dialog>
```

The component element is breaking the between `md-dialog` and m`d-toolbar`, `md-dialog-content` and `md-dialog-actions` leads to a layout break and the `md-toolbar` and the `md-dialog-actions` are not fixed.

So my question is, is there a way to only render the component template contents without the component element (`<publish-dialog></publish-dialog>`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your directive, try using `replace: true`.

From [How to use `replace` of directive definition?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15285635/how-to-use-replace-of-directive-definition)